# get ipv6 address from addrinfo struct in windows xp

Tags: c, windows-xp, winsock, ipv6, getaddrinfo

how is it possible to get an ipv6 address from a addrinfo struct under windows xp?
is there any other possibility than WSAAddressToString (has anyone ever successfully used that one?) ?

```
getaddrinfo(server_ip, port, &hints, &result)
addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*) rp->ai_addr;
WSAAddressToString((struct sockaddr*) rp, (DWORD) sizeof(*addr), 0, ipbuf, &iplen); //cant get it to work
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`WSAAddressToString(rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen, NULL, ipbuf, &iplen);`

You're passing an addrinfo as a sockaddr in your example. (I assume rp is iterating over the results or something.)